# '80s/'90s post-apocalyptic book series about a military-type guy and a cult that lives near nuclear areas

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

It's a post-apocalyptic/dystopian future that takes place after a nuclear war. The main character is a military-type guy. There's a cult that lives near nuclear areas and gets green spots and try to get everyone to do the same. I don't remember much else. On the cover the main character was really muscular and brunette.

I had a few of them 20ish years ago, but I only remember the reading one. I got them in a bag of books from a giveaway somewhere and most of them were from Tor Press. There was a football stadium at the end. I think he was trying to get all the followers there to explode them or something?
I have tried googling and I have failed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

David Robbins's Endworld series. Specifically the green spots are in [Dallas Run](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6559868-dallas-run), which is the 20th book in the series.

[image: Dallas Run]

The greenspots are a mark of the devotees of cult, and they use an old stadium as their temple, which is why you remember the stadium. The protagonist *Blade* first discovers the existence of the cult when he meets a cult member *Marta*:

> "We can't take any chances," Sergeant Whitney said. "There's a possibility you're infected with a disease."
> "I am not," Marta responded indignantly.
> "Then what are those green spots all over you?"
> Marta touched one of the inch-wide irregular splotches on her left thigh. "Do you mean these?"
> "What are they?"
> She traced the outline of the splotch with her finger. "Isn't it beautiful?"
> "Miss?"
> "Such exquisite design. The Maker is magnificent."

The head of the cult is called *The Lawgiver*:

> Blade couldn't stop himself from doing a double take. Like the rest of
> the Chosen, the Lawgiver's body was covered with the green splotches.
> Unlike the others, the elderly man's face was a shiny shade of green from his forehead to his chin. And what a face! The visage resembled a
> predatory bird of prey, an eagle or a hawk. A great, hooked nose divided a perpetually puckered pair of thin, cruel lips and a pair of eerie, dazzling green eyes. Wrinkles creased the Lawgiver's forehead and cheeks, suggesting an age well beyond the normal life expectancy.

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thank you!!!